# Any ideas what these Doctor Who monsters are?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification

I have these Doctor Who action figures and would like to know what they are.

[image: Dr Who Action Figures]

Comment: The first looks somewhat like an Ice Warrior -- perhaps some variety?

Comment: The first image that alexwlchan posted is a Melkur from the episode "The Keeper of Traken", see http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/keepertraken/

Comment: Fixed now. I've added them as pics from OPs G+ account and combined them into a single question.

Comment: Hypnosifl and Alexwlchan answered first. I'd hate to grab their credit by giving an answer :)

Comment: @MacCooper - I plan to do exactly that. My answer is a veritable masterpiece of research and accuracy ;-)

Comment: ah, the Sontaran Warrior... good stuff!

Answer (score 18):

The "monsters" you've posted are a [Melkur](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Melkur) and a [Sontaran Warrior](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sontaran).

The figures themselves were created by a company called DaPol to cash in on the 1996 [Doctor Who film](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_(TV_story)). You can find others in the same series [here](http://www.figurerealm.com/checklist.php?action=checklist&universeid=&seriesid=742&subid=4).

[image]

Answer (score -3):

The first one looks like an ice warrior and the second looks like a Sontaran.

Comment: What is an "ice warrior"? (I didn't downvote you, btw.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I know it's wikipedia, but: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Warrior

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Well, that's embarrassing. Back in 2015, I clearly hadn't seen the *Cold War* episode yet, let alone *The Empress of Mars* from the new series :-)

Comment: It's OK. Anyone who didn't watch the show in the 1960s-70s wouldn't know about the Ice Warriors anyway.